# И еще этимология — "бердыш".

Tags: этимология

Бердыш — русское холодное оружие типа алебарды, насаженный на копье топор. А что означает название?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По Далю этимология такова:
БЕ́РДЫШ м. стар. широкий топор, иногда с гвоздевым обухом и с копьем, на длинном ратовище; алебарда, протазан. Бердыш перешло от нас на север Европы, где, по свойству готского языка, к нему привесили an: bardis, bardisan; во Франции из этого сделали pertuisane, и слово это позже воротилось к нам, обратясь в протазан (Вельтман). Идти в рать, так бердыш брать. Бе́рдышный к оружию этому относящийся. Бе́рдышник м. воин, вооруженный бердышом; протазанник, алебардник.

Answer (score -1):

Даля - в топку. Его этимологические извски не выдерживают никакой критики. Что вы хотите от дядьки, не имевшего даже "начального" филологического образования???

Бердыш - заимствовано латинского через польский, французам не требовалось помощи славян, чтобы взять слово из "своей" же латыни.

бердыш
бе́рды́ш "боевой топор, алебарда", бардыш – то же (Поликарпов, Лексикон 1704 г.). Заимств. через польск. bardysz, berdysz из ср.-лат. barducium "метательное копье, легкий топорик" (Дюканж), по мнению Линде; см. Миккола, Berühr. I, 84 и сл., Бернекер 1, 44, Брюкнер 21. Последний (KZ 48, 161) выступает против мнения Агреля об исконнослав. происхождении. Возведение к нем. Barte, вопреки Маценауэру (105) и Преобр. (1, 23), невозможно. •• [бердыш уже с 1660 г.; см. Фогараши, "Studia Slavica", 4, 1958, стр. 64. – Т.]